# Only first script is getting executed from TestNG XML

Tags: xml, testng

I tried running the below mentioned testNG XML using testNG suite which has 2 scripts in it, but only the first script is getting executed and the second class fails just after launching the browser and shutting it down immediately.

I have the browser launching and teardown methods in Base class as Beforemethod and Aftermethod respectively. When i tried executing the second script as an individual testNG test, it is properly getting executed. This is happening not only for this combination of classes. Any 2 or 3 scripts I place it in XML, only the first script is getting executed and for rest of the scripts only browser launch and shutting down happening.

I couldn't figure out the issue in this XML file. I have pasted the snapshot of Base class too. Can someone please help me on identifying this issue.

[XML File link /](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo26q.png) - [Results_Failure/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKEIG.png)[Before_Method/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/926GJ.png)[After_Method/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL4HI.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Suite">
      <test name="Test">
        <classes>
          <class name="projectScripts.Scenario_Login"/>
          <class name="projectScripts.Scenario_Search_Addtocart"/>
          <class name="projectScripts.Scenario_DeleteCart"/>
        </classes>
      </test> <!-- Test -->
    </suite> <!-- Suite --> 


    @BeforeMethod
    public void launchApp() throws Exception{

        String browsertype = c1.Reading_properties("BTYPE");
        if (browsertype.equals("firefox"))
        {
        driver =new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if(browsertype.equals("chrome"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Framework_Practise\\Drivers\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver =new ChromeDriver();
            }
        else if(browsertype.equals("ie"))
        {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D:\\Framework_Practise\\Drivers\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver =new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }

        driver.get(c1.Reading_properties("URL"));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //implicit wait
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

} 


    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(){        
        driver.quit();

        ereports.endTest(starttest);
        ereports.flush();
    }
```

Comment: Could you add your code as text formatted as code (indented with 4 spaces) istead of adding them as images?

Comment: Hi, I have added now the XML file and the methods as text file

Comment: @NaveenAnand - You havent shared the test code. You have merely shared just the configuration method. Rather than sharing a google drive link, I would encourage you to edit your question and update it with the code and also the suite xml contents. That way its all easily available to be looked at in one single place.